# A directory structure for Django on Linux

Tags: linux, django, apache

I've got a linux machine that I use solely for (multiple) Django projects. I'm looking for the best place to put everything. Currently I'm using the following directories -

- `/home/Code/my_project` to put the django project itself (ie the code created by `start_project`)
- `/home/Code/virtualenvs/my_project_env` for the virtualenv
- `/home/www/my_project` for apache logs

On top of this I've been keeping my static root and media root directories within the main project code -

- `/home/Code/my_project/static_root`
- `/home/Code/my_project/media`

The big issue I've hit with this setup is that I'm running out of disk space on `/home`. I feel that I should at least be keeping my static files in `/var` somewhere. Should the apps themselves go in `/opt`?

How should I set this up next time? What can I do about my disk space issues with current apps? (Is this really a sys admin question?)

Comment: Apart from anything else, I don't understand at all how the code is living separately from the virtualenv.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I activate the virtualenv manually if I'm actually logged into the server, and I've added it to the mod_wsgi python path in the apache vhost. I manage the virtualenv with a requirements.txt file that's committed into the git repo.